# DOS script to check if the default java installed version is greater than 1.x

Tags: java, windows, scripting

As the subject said, i need a dos script to check the version of java installed on windows xp Machine.
Furthermore, I need to check if the version is greater than a prefixed value 1.x.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the version, and write it into a temp file. Then only parse the version itself:

```
@echo off
echo off
java -version 2> tmp_java_version.txt
set /p JAVA_VERSION= < tmp_java_version.txt
del tmp_java_version.txt
set JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:~14,3%

echo %JAVA_VERSION%
pause > NUL
```

Comment: It can be the case where java is not set in path but installed.

Comment: Afaik, if Java is installed, there is also a java.exe in the System32 directory, which means, java can be called from every position in the shell. Therefore there shouldn't be a problem. Maybe the var is empty, but you have to check it anyway.

Comment: well, how do you parse the file then without installing any additional tools?

Comment: How can you parse something with nothing? The script gives the result (the version) in a temp. file. So you can use that for your next actions. You could use a RegEx to get more details like major and minor versions or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -version
```

You can also use the command

```
java -fullversion
```

and produce output such as:

java full version "1.6.0_17-b04"

On a computer without any version of Java from Sun Microsystems installed, this results in an error message:

'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In a batch you could do:

```
@echo off
java.exe -fullversion 2> c:\temp\out.txt
for /F "tokens=4" %%i IN (c:\temp\out.txt) DO echo %%i
```

You can't avoid the temp file because the java.exe output writes on the standard error! So you have to redirect the standard error to a file.

Answer (score 0):

if you can download and  [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) for windows.

```
C:\test>java -version 2>&1 | gawk "NR==1{print $3}"
"1.6.0_16"
```

Answer (score 0):

In commmand prompt you can just type it has `java -version.`

For example:

```
D:\Users> java -version
```

then you will get the answer as

```
java version 1.8.0_11
```